# tableviewcell separator moved in ios 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, separator, uitableview

I'm creating tableviews and cells programmatically. The tableview cell separator moved in iOS 8,

[image]

even if I have already set:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return kSomeNumber;
}
```

My app is ios7 and my phone is ios8. What could be the problem?
I can't use cell.layoutMargins which is for ios8 only

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "separator moved"?

Comment: Hi the cell height is the same but the separator moved upwards

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS8 we have layoutMargins which is causing your line.

If you have a custom cell, add this method to remove it:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins 
{
     return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Or add this in you uitableviewcontroller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```

The responsToSelector is needed in order to support iOS7

Also check [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working) for more info

Comment: Thanks! Just implementing `-layoutMargins` in my custom UITableViewCell class did the trick (and works fine on iOS 7.)