# Auto Layout in Xcode 6 - Pinning view to edge of parent view creates -8 constraint

Tags: uicollectionview, autolayout, ios8, xcode6

In Xcode 6 when I try to pin an image view to the edge of `UICollectionViewCell`, auto-layout creates constraints of -8.0. What changed? I've tried to find release notes or documentation updates but haven't seen anything.

1. Notice the imageview is up against the edges of the collectionview cell

[image]

2. Frame X and Y are both zero

[image: frame]

3. Adding constraints for leading space and trailing space to container margin results in a settings of -8.0

[image: constraints]

Why is this happening and what is the preferred approach for edge to edge content?

Comment: Change the "Show" pop-up in your middle screenshot to "Layout Rectangle". Are the X and Y still 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you add a new constraint, you will need to **untick** the "**Constain to Margins**". It is ticked by default.

[image]

Comment: Why he has to do that? whats the propose of this tick ?

Comment: in iOS 8, there is one new property call "layout margins" for all the views inherit from UIView. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working/25788003#25788003