# How to make table cells and separator full width in iOS 8 with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8, monotouch.dialog

We have a number of table views (using Xamarin Monotouch Dialog) that are plain (not grouped) and are designed to appear full-width without indents. This all works fine in iOS 7. Using the iOS 8 simulator though, we're getting a slight left indent.

iOS 8 has a new property called LayoutMargins. We're setting that property to zero. Like this:

```
if (this.TableView.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("setSeparatorInset:")))
    this.TableView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

if (this.TableView.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("setLayoutMargins:")))
    this.TableView.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
```

That had some effect - it removed about half the indent. But we're still seeing a slight indent. Is there another property that controls the indent in iOS 8?

Here's a screenshot...
[image]

Comment: Anyone have code for how to do this with xamarin.forms for ios?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25770119/220643) you need to do this on the `UITableView` **and** on your `UITableViewCell` subclasses.

Another person (same post) overrode the `LayoutMargins` property on the `UITableViewCell` subclass to always return `UIEdgeInsets.Zero`.

Comment: This worked great. That's twice today you've answered my question! Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

In c#,
tableView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;