# How to set the full width of separator in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where the separators don't have the full width. It ends like 10 pixels before the left side. I was playing around with this code in the `viewDidLoad()`.

```
self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Also in the storyboard when you can select custom or default selectors. Now all the cells that are populated don't have the full-width selectors but the cells that are empty have full width.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `UITableView` has a property `separatorInset`. Set the inset of the `UITableView`line separator to zero. Also you can change the `separatorInset` from the storyboard

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I got the answer from this post: [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Just add this code on your `UITableViewController`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Comment: it works for me for adding only the tableView delegate method

Comment: Im sorry i did not understad. You mean that it was enough for you to add the TableViewDeleagte?. I just tried just adding that it did not work for me @TonyTony

Comment: for me the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not necessary

Comment: DId you try to run your code with other IOS versions than 8? Maybe it works for the newest ones. Otherwise good for you that it works. I tried just adding the tableview delegate method and it did not help. @TonyTony

Comment: I had to use both. I tried using each individually with no success. It only worked when I used both. In addition, I tried it when my view controller was a subclass of UITableViewController, and when it was a subclass of UIViewController. No difference. Note that I'm running in the 8.1 simulator.

Comment: it pains me to have to say this, but the iOS SDK is slowly becoming a disaster. Why would adjusting the separator insert be so tedious. Gosh.

Comment: Note that this won't adjust the separators on 'placeholder' cells displayed by the controller to fill up the view below your cells if you cells don't make up the full height.

Comment: For future users: on iOS 9 you need both.

Comment: @WMios are you sure? I just tried iOS 9.3 (13E230) and implementation of `viewDidLoad` is not needed (willDisplayCell works alone).

Comment: It's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which differs from `viewDidLoad` and in the end I did not need it.

Answer (score 238):

This worked for me on iOS 8.4 - 9.0 devices using Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()


    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    return cell
}
```

**Swift 5 Update:**

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: Why does this remove my table with a blank one? The seperators are moved but I cant see any of my buttons

Comment: @James could you please explain " remove my table with a blank one?". How have you added your buttons (via IB, code)?

Comment: Very nice solution. But in my case I put code straight to the cell initialization, beacuse I wanted to have full width of separator in all controllers.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, this also works for Objective-C with the proper syntax changes of course.

Comment: cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero is enough if you have insets = 0 for tableview separators in storyboard/xib. preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins is false by default.

Comment: None of these solutions work on an iPad. This only works on an iPhone...

Comment: @Hannah Louisa Carney answer is better. This leaves default insets for empty rows.

Answer (score 109):

In your `UITableViewCell`

Go to Attributes Inspector in your Interface Builder and simply change "15" to 0. Do this for all the cells you wish to change.

[image: instets]

You may need to add `[cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];` to your `tableViewCell`

Comment: Or that's weird.  This did work for me (thank you !) on the rows where I had UITableViewCells to be displayed, but on any empty rows below them, the separator was still indented by 15 pixels.

Comment: If you are using static cells, all you need is to change the left inset to 0 like described in the image (Working in iOS 10, Xcode 8.3.1)

Answer (score 30):

for Swift 3 :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  tableView.separatorInset = .zero
  tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
}
```

Answer (score 25):

1. Select your `UITableViewCell`
2. Go to ***Atributes Inspector***
3. Go to ***Separator*** and change it to *"custom Insets"*
4. Set `left` and / or `right` fields. (By default `left: 15`, `right: 0`)

Look how it works (using `left: 100`):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: duplicate of previous answer from @Hannah Louisa Carney

Answer (score 19):

I inherit from `UITableViewController` and needed additional to the two insets settings in `willDisplayCell` also to set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` to false. In Swift it looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:") {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:") {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:") {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false` because default value is already false

Comment: Note that this won't adjust the separators on 'placeholder' cells displayed by the controller to fill up the view below your cells if you cells don't make up the full height.

Answer (score 12):

The Separator `Inset` is by default 15 from left. Change Separator `Inset` option from `auto` to `custom` and set the inset to `0`.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For Swift in iOS 9+

If using a custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
override var layoutMargins: UIEdgeInsets {
    get { return UIEdgeInsetsZero }
    set(newVal) {}
}
```

then for your `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.tableView?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: This is the only answer that fixed it for me (updated to swift 3). However... it works when there is data in the cell. For blank cells that have not yet been filled (and I guess haven't called this overriden layoutMargins variable) the separator still does not fill the full width of my custom cell in the tableview. Any ideas on that?

Comment: On the iPhone, the separator ends just a few pixels from the left and a few pixels from the right on empty cells. That looks alright without using this trick to zero out the margins. On the iPad is the real problem - the separators on an empty cell go from the left edge of the tableview, only about 80% of the width of the cell. When there is data in the cell, the separator is still 80% of the cell width, but it starts 20% of the way in and goes all the way to the right edge of the tableview

Comment: Figured out a solution... using if #available(iOS 9, *) { self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false } made it so I don't need your code at all on iPhone. The separator just goes the full width. On iPad, the empty cells have a full width separator, but I need your code in order to keep full width when data is added. Otherwise, there are a few pixels to the left added where there is no separator once data fills the cell.

Comment: Answer where I got the code in the comment above from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31538250/428981

Answer (score 9):

Use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, to configure cell's separator specs ,
it works perfect for iOS9.0+

```
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
 cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
 cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
```

Answer (score 9):

For people having issues with the iPad — this will get you in a state that is the same as the iPhone. You can then adjust the `separatorInset` as needed.

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

Comment: This was my problem on iOS 10 vs iOS 11. iOS 11 was fine, but 10 had different margins. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

Tested for iOS 9.3 & Swift 2.2. Make sure to put the code in `willDisplayCell` which is called just before displaying the cell and not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you create the cell only.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Add `override` to the function for `UITableViewController`, like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

Answer (score 8):

swift 5, Xcode 11 Update

place this inside viewDidLoad()

```
yourTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

for edge to edge separator just set the value of left and right to 0.

by the way change the "yourTableView" to your tableView Outlet name.

Comment: Swift 5 you can simple use `UIEdgeInsets.zero`

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me in Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1

Turned out to be the simplest solution of all. No code needed. Just change `TableViewCell` Layout Margins values in your `UITableView` inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3 :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset)) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.layoutMargins)) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad` (tested iOS11 - swift 4.1)

try

`tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions work on the iPad, but I have come up with a solution that covers both devices:

**With reusable cells:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    ...[other code]...
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    return cell;
}
```

**With non reusable cells:**

```
- (void)removeSeparatorInset:(UITableView*)tableView{
    NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells];
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells){
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   [self removeSeparatorInset:self.tableView];
}
```

Just to expand on this approach:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets separatorInset;
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets layoutMargins;
```

Both properties can be used by `UITableView` & `UITableViewCell`.
The latter is, in fact, a property of `UIView`, which is a parent class of both `UITableView` & `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: The only workable solution I found for non reusable cells