# How to make an equal width separator for tableViewCell on storyboard without by adding another UIView?

Tags: ios, storyboard

How to make an equal width separator for `UITableViewCell` on a storyboard  without adding another `UIView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}
```

from [How to set the full width of separator in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519248/how-to-set-the-full-width-of-separator-in-uitableview)