# tableview cell moved to the left (swift3)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

[image]
The bottom of my cells have a small indent to the left. I have noticed this several times. How can I remove this and make sure there is no gap on the left.

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519248/how-to-set-the-full-width-of-separator-in-uitableview

Comment: thats it! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the separatorInset to UIEdgeInsetsZero, then there's no gap on the left. If you mean the content on the content view of the cell, subclass the UITableViewCell.