# Separator on the last UITableViewCell not added?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This is how my UITableView looks like:

[image]

I might cut the image to close to the last cell but there is no separator on the last cell.

When running this on my device that has IOS 7.1.1 It gets the same result until i scroll the view up and down a bit and then it automatically adds the separator. But trying that in the simulator which is running on IOS 8.2 as you can se nothing happens.

So what i want is simply so the separator is visible from the start.

Many thanks

**EDIT1**

After trying the answer below it did work however when there are a lot of cells and you scroll up then an extra separator shows up as you can see.

[image]

Check the third last cell. That extra separator just follows me when i go up and down.

**EDIT2**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
    {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
    {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
        return 76.0f;
    else
        return 25.0f;
}
```

Comment: do you dynamically calculate the height of each cell? Is it possible that you get fractional heights (< 0.5 pt) from these calculations? If so try to `ceil( )` these values. My separator issues disappeared after I avoided row heights like 22.38947

Comment: No i have a fixed height that i set for them @MatthiasBauch

Comment: There are so many bugs in `UITableView` separator. I always create my own seperator by adding a line in `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Would you mind sharing that code?  @VietHung

Answer (score 3):

Use the two below UITableView delegate methods

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView* view = [UIView new];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
return view;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thnx

Comment: Are you also implementing the viewForHeader and heightForHeader methods? Do you mind adding all your code that has to do with your table view so I can take a look?

Comment: No i am not implementing those methods, yes i will put all the relevant stuff

Comment: Add `if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }`                                                                                                        in the `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: Nope the bottom footer still keeps following me. Also edit your answer and insert the code there. it's easier.

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you. It seems very similar to your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try to add footer view for table with 1 0r 2 pixel height.

Answer (score 0):

This worked flawlessly for me

```
self.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]
```