# Using Storyboard, how do I add a padding to my TableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, interface-builder

I dragged out an entire TableViewController and made some custom cells. The cells are displaying fine. However, the entire table view hugging the top

What do I have to do to make some "padding" to the top?

[image: .]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using Auto-layout, re-set the table frame with a 20 Inset on top.

If you use Auto-layout, set the top constraint's constant to 20.

**Extra Stuff**

[image]

and look at `tableView.separatorInset`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can make the separator touch the left hand side?

Comment: I changed the inset from 15 to / 0. The storyboard did show a slight "twitch", indicating that it moved. However, during run time, it doesn't take effect? It seems to be the same.

Comment: @TIMEX try to do it in code: `tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, rightInset) `

Comment: @TIMEX I found the great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working).  Check it~

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add padding for your tableview , add the code in viewWillAppear.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can make the separator touch the left hand side?