# Set separator inset for single UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to set separator inset for a single UITableViewCell? It seems I can only set global UITableView separator inset with `setSeparatorInset:` method, but I would like to have different insets in the same UITableView. Is it possible somehow?

I tried using `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` for setting separator inset in a concrete UITableViewCell as below, but it does not work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...
  [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0)];
}
```

I am working on iOS7.

Comment: try to write that in uitableview delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: That won't work. Problem is `setSeparatorInset:` method exists in UITableView, so if I use it it will change separator inset for the whole UITableView, not for a concrete cell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the cell's `indexPath`. You can set it using

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Customize here
       [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0)];
    } else {
       [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
}`

If not, you are supposed to subclass `UITableView` and customize separator insets there. Then load it into your tableview. DO NOT set `separatorInset` property both in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and `subclasses`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using custom cells.
You set your `UITableView` to not show separators at all (`separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`) and have your `UITableViewCell` subclass handle the drawing of the separators. The easiest way would be to have a "separator view" on each cell. Now when configuring your cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set whatever inset that you like.