# Separator lines for UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cells not taking the full width

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have prepared [a simple test project](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/q6/MySubtitle) for my question at GitHub.

When using [UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) type of cells (called *Subtitle* in Xcode Interface Builder) - for some reason the horizontal lines are not reaching the left side of the screen:

[image: app screenshot]

At the above screenshot you can see that the separator lines in "empty cells" are occupying the whole width just fine.

First I thought that the icons (size: [46 x 46 pixels](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/q6/MySubtitle/MySubtitle/graphics)) were not fitting into the cells and tried to increase the row height, but this does not help.

Also I have tried to set **Custom Insets** to **Custom** and there **Left** to 0 pixels (both for *Table View* and for *MyCell*), but there is still a gap on the left side:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Here the source code of my [TableViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/q6/MySubtitle/MySubtitle/TableViewController.m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[
        @{@"title": @"Title 1", @"subtitle": @"Sub Title 1", @"icon": @"signal4.png"},
        @{@"title": @"Title 2", @"subtitle": @"Sub Title 2", @"icon": @"signal1.png"},
        @{@"title": @"Title 3", @"subtitle": @"Sub Title 3", @"icon": @"signal2.png"},
        @{@"title": @"Title 4", @"subtitle": @"Sub Title 4", @"icon": @"signal3.png"}
    ]];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary* item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item[@"subtitle"];
    UIImage* icon = [UIImage imageNamed:item[@"icon"]];
    [cell.imageView setImage:icon];

    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The source code from this answer has helped me at the end: 
[iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

[image: fixed screenshot]

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
           [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

/*
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Force your tableview margins (this may be a bad idea)
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
} 
*/
```

Comment: in iOS 8 you have to add some code to do so. Check the answer

Comment: Alexander, long time no see! :) Can I persuade you not to do this? There are aesthetic reasons why there are insets and why the insets are changed when there is an image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add Table View Separator Insets to Zero. Not Just for Table View Cell.

[image]

Add this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //....
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]>=8.0)
    {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }
}
```

Integration with your code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]>=8.0)
    {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }

    NSDictionary* item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item[@"subtitle"];
    UIImage* icon = [UIImage imageNamed:item[@"icon"]];
    [cell.imageView setImage:icon];

    return cell;
}
```

See the preview :

[image]

Comment: Ok, Then let wait for another answer @AlexanderFarber

Comment: Brilliant! It's a pity there is no Nobel Prize for working around stupid iOS behavior. Of course, this solution comes at a price: the developer may have other reasons for _not_ wanting to change the cell margins. But there are ways around that (add a subview with margins of its own).

Comment: Just to be clear: there is no need to involve the table. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set three things: (1) The cell's separator inset; (2) the cell's layout margins; (3) the cell's `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins`. That will do it.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thanks for the answer. However, after doing this some spaces are again left. Is there any way to cover those as well?