# Change tableView separator insets

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, cell

I'm incurred in a little problem customizing my cell;

[image]

as you can see the separator line do not reach the left border of the cell, and a I'd like to do it. I found these:

- [Separator lines for UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cells not taking the full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168168/separator-lines-for-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-cells-not-taking-the-full-width)
- [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Can anyone help me to translate in swift code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For conversion of the answer ([Separator lines for UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cells not taking the full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168168/separator-lines-for-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-cells-not-taking-the-full-width)) in Swift

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourcell") as! UITableViewCell

    if (cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
}
```

By Checking version number :

```
let floatVersion = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue

if (floatVersion > 8.0){
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}
```

Comment: @FabioCelli did you added separator custom insets to 0?

Comment: I had already do it, but did not work; now closing and reopening Xcode works (???).

Comment: @FabioCelli That's good. You have to just convert my obj-c answer to swift then it should work well :) Anyways happy to hear that it is working.

Comment: @iAshish, FYI, Apple doesn't want us to use respondToSelector anymore, you can find information about it in the stateoftheunion video from the WWDC

Comment: @Loegic Ok, I we can check by the version number because iOS 7 does not have preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Loegic can you give me the link in that they have written that you can not use the `respondToSelector` ?

Comment: @iAshish You can watch it here (Swift 2 improvement) https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=102 and I believe Natashatherobot spoke about it on her blog http://natashatherobot.com

Comment: @iAshish I found it, it's a new API called availability checking (#available()), implement it this way : The following code snippet is copied from the WWDC2015 Session 106 What's New in Swift 

The Old Approach:
@ IBOutlet var dropButton: NSButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
if dropButton.respondsToSelector("setSpringLoaded:") {
dropButton.springLoaded = true
}
}

The Better Approach:
@ IBOutlet var dropButton: NSButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
if #available(OSX 10.10.3, *) {
dropButton.springLoaded = true
}
}

Comment: @Loegic Ok. I will check. Thanks for the links :)

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset))) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }

    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins))) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.layoutMargins))) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is old version and it doesn't work anymore.

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

You can use this (for swift, in Objective C you can call the same thing)

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Answer (score 3):

the second link should work.

swift version:

```
if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}

if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) {
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your `cellForRowAtIndePath` method:

```
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:") {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:") {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:") {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
```