# How to make separatorInset of Tableview for all Rows?

Tags: uitableview, swift, tableview, rows

My app has a tableview with separatorInset setting for all rows like this:

```
self.tableView.separatorInset.left = 0
self.tableView.separatorInset.right = 0
```

But when I ran my code, all of my rows have a separatorInset good except the first row like this:

[image]

How can I set separatorInset for all rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working