# cell separator line in uitableview not covering the complete width

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm calling `setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` on a `UITableView` instance. The separator line should cover completely the width of table but instead it starts with some inset from the left. How can I have the separator line span the entire width of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this codes it will be ok :

In method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
```

EDIT :
Changed code lines according to this post : [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Comment: You can also use just this two lines of code : cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero; cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code which work for me in iOS 7 & 8 both version -

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works on 7.0 and after.

You should set in your table view the desired inset:

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
{
    [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
{
    [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Also you configure your cells like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)])
    {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    return cell;
}
```