# Custom UITableViewCell adds space to right side

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a custom table view cell with a label and a button, but for some reason the separator line under the custom cells on the right side is cut off. I checked the  Custom Separator Inset in the Storyboard and it's 15 on the left, and 0 on the right. I even tried to set the Inset programmatically using   tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero and cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero, but that didn't work either. And suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[See picture][1]

Update- Solved: So I made the custom cells in the storyboard using an iPhone 5 size screen and the simulate was an iPhone 6 so I guess the cell width wasn't long enough.

Comment: Why you don't use autolayout?

Comment: this is duplicate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working

Comment: please do a search before sending the question.

Comment: Hey this friend's problem is that the separator is cut off from the right side.

Comment: Ehsan looking at the link you posted I'm not sure it's the same problem. I tried converting the Objective-C to swift but it seems like adding        `cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false`    `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero`  before the  `return cell`  should seem to work, yet the tableview still looks like the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your table view's data source. I personally use this code and this will work whatever your storyboard settings are.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if tableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")) { tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero }
    if tableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) { tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero }
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) { cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero }
}
```

Comment: Added that to the MyFriendsTableViewController.swift and the tableView still looks like the picture I posted! I'm thinking I might have to edit the customcell file