# How do I make the UITableView separator inset go from the edges of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class RoomNewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var row:Int?
    var room: Room?{
        didSet{
            updateUI() //this is when render is called
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero 
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0) 
    }



    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func updateUI(){
        println("Updating UI")
        let test = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        test.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.addSubview(test)
    }

}
```

}

This is how I create my tableView:

```
    //Draw Table
    self.roomsTableView.delegate = self
    self.roomsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.roomsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    self.roomsTableView.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: 0xededed)
    let tableViewStartY = CGFloat(0) //used to be 20.0
    let extraPaddingToAlignTable = CGFloat(50)
    self.roomsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, tableViewStartY, screenWidth, CGRectGetMinY(self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame) + extraPaddingToAlignTable)
    self.roomsTableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
    self.roomsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)


    self.roomsTableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(100)
    self.roomsTableView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.roomsTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.roomsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.roomsTableView.registerClass(RoomNewTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newCell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.roomsTableView)
```

I've tried playing around separatorInset for **both** the table and cell, but can't seem to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since launch of iOS 8.0, apple added layoutMargins property for UITableViewCell and UITableView.

So you can set layoutMargin to zero in `willDisplayCell:` delegate method of TableView. This code just set tableview `layoutMargin` and cell `layoutMargin` as `UIEdgeInsetsZero` .

This will work for iOS 7.0 also.

Try this may help you.

**Swift**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if(tableView.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:")){

            tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

        if(tableView.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:")){

            tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

        if(cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:")){

            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

    }
```

**Objective C**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

   if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```

For iOS 9.0, you have to set `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth`  to `NO`.

**Objective C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //For iOS 9 and Above 

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //For iOS 9 and Above 
        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
        }
    }
```

You can also set this value from Storyboard.

Open Storyboard and go to Attribute Inspector for TableView Cell.

Change type of `Separator` field to `Custom Insets`  and change value of `Left` to `0`.

Please find below image.

[image]