# UITableView width constraint isn't working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, constraints

I have an `UITableView` object that I've added one constraint to it: width equal to `view` (the container view).

But for some reason it seems the `tableView` is bigger than the view:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: with which View u give constraint ?

Comment: from which angle we check that table view is bigger then the view? how can we identifier ?

Comment: @bhargavbajani The container view

Comment: @NitinGohel Do you see the tableView's lines are not ending as expected (they are being cut at the end)

Comment: i think its default white space ... change background color of cell and check

Comment: this is not tablview issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working check this you need to setting inset 0 then that seperator line full width of tableview.

Comment: @EICaptain I mean the seperator lines, they are being cut on the right and not ending like they are started

Comment: By default, the separators are inset on the left, but not the right.

Comment: yes... the same I suggest ... its a default behaviour of tableview seperator

Comment: @EICaptain Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

The view is not bigger as you have identified already, it is due to the TableView Separator Inset, and you can change it from the storyboard itself.

[image]

View debugging is also very helpful in finding this kind of issues, you can debug your view from

**Debug** - **View Debugging** - **Capture View Hierarchy**.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm trying to change left to 0 in the storyboard and it's not changing anything

Comment: It should change, provide screen shot.