# Can't make seperator insets in UI table view custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make separators with 20 pt insets from left and right. 
whatever I do I still get a full line from one edge to the other.

what I tried: 
In attributes inspector choose separator - Custom Inset and added 20 pixel from left and right.

I also tried in `viewDidLoad` -

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)
```

I still get a full line.. 
any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `setSeparatorInset` in `willDisplayCell`,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
           [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
    }
}
```

Reference : [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can set separator insets in interface builder as well

Go to attribute inspector there you change under separator inset to the value whatever u want