# Listview Separator Inset Full Width

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

So to my surprise, I haven't found anything on the web or SO on this particular issue. I'm trying to make my listview separator inset to be full width. I have found documentation on this for a tableview, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working). But it's not clear to me how to do this for a listview as well? I am using Xamarin Forms listview, trying to accomplish this on iOS. I imagine I have to write a custom renderer, seeing as no (publically exposed) property is available on forms for a listview.

This is a good picture that is happening for me on a listview, although the image shown is from a SO question regarding tableview, not listview, but the issue seems to be the same.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you are using Xamarin Forms 3.0+ or earlier versions.

### Xamarin Forms 3.0 and higher

A `ListView` on Xamarin Forms 3.0 and higher now exposes a `SeparatorStyle` property which can be set to a `SeparatorStyle` enum value, either `Default` or `FullWidth`. This has been provided via [this PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1854).

Make sure to set the `SeparatorStyle` property to `FullWidth` in order to achieve the wanted effect.

### Before Xamarin Forms 3.0

You are correct that there isn't a property exposed through the Xamarin Forms `ListView` (which ultimately [renders as a `UITableView` on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs)) to change the separator width. If you want to change the separator yourself, you will have to resort to a custom renderer and implement what you found in the other SO question.

As a workaround, you could disable the separator visibility and then add a `BoxView` of 1 height to simulate a full width separator.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Saw [this](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/04/29/xamarin-forms-custom-listview-separator-without-boxview) just the other day for this very thing.

Comment: @hvaughan3 Keep in mind that Stefan's comment on your link is a valid one, nesting `StackLayout` instead of using a `BoxView` probably isn't the best option regarding performance.

Comment: Good point and completely agree with you. It is why I never implemented something like what is in the link myself.

Comment: yeah i wouldnt ever do that lol, i appreciate the link though. guess we're just gonna deal with the non-full width separator. So annoying, this should be a property...

Comment: It's too specific to iOS to add as a `ListView` property. Xamarin Forms has to look for a common denominator over all platforms when creating abstractions like `ListView`. It would be hard to deal with every possible usage scenario, so it's left out. It's a little hassle, but you get the ability to adjust your renderer to your specific needs.

Comment: this answer is no logner valid. Since Xamarin.Forms 3.0 this is handled with a platform specific: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1665

Comment: Thanks @GiampaoloGabba, I've updated the answer to differentiate between the different Xamarin Forms versions

Comment: MAUI solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/listview-separator-style?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get the list view separator to go full width using a custom renderer.

Tested on iOS 11.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace MasterDetailNav1.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is now built in with Xamarin Forms 3.0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/ios#setting-the-separator-style-on-a-listview

Simply set the `SeparatorStyle` to either `Default` or `FullWidth` on your `ListView` (be aware this is a platform specific for iOS, Android does full width by default):

```
<ListView ios:ListView.SeparatorStyle="FullWidth"/>
```

Comment: this is the latest link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/listview-separator-style and this line is required to function using xaml:     xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"

Answer (score 0):

separator fullwidth:

```
<ListView ios:ListView.SeparatorStyle="FullWidth"/>
```

Separator color property in list view

& remove separator when no content in view cell

https://xamgirl.com/quick-trick-remove-extra-separator-line-in-listview-xamarin-forms-ios/

Comment: this is completely unrelated to the question. The OP was asking for separator fullwidth not for separator color or to remove extra separator at the ned of a listview

Comment: Sorry, as you can notice there is a " : " because its supposed to be the example of the fullWidth property. Also I consider that's it would be nice to show an example of removing the separator when the cell has no content and apply a color. I update my comment, stop crying please

Comment: In fact when I try to edit the comment I see : <ListView ios:ListView.SeparatorStyle="FullWidth"/> but its not showing.

Comment: Check solution in MAUI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/listview-separator-style?view=net-maui-7.0