# Swift remove TableCell margin

Tags: swift, uitableview, tablecell

Although similar questions have been asked quite often, I still couldn't find out the exact solution. What I am trying to do now is to remove the left and right border/margin in the TableCell entirely like the below.

[Existing problematic TableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QfbC.png)
[image]

[ideal TableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFw4f.jpg) 
[image]

I tried to add the below codes in func tableview (...cellForRowAt...) but it doesn't work,

```
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Its better u can take separate uiview

Comment: Please refer this post. it's helpfull :[UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877725/6822622)